# How can i make blueman work without pulseaudio?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa

Recently I have been having Bluetooth headset troubles, I think PulseAudio might be the problem so i have uninstalled PulseAudio and I plan to just use alsa, however since uninstalling PulseAudio blueman no longer wants to connect to my headset, all of the answers I have seen involve reinstalling PulseAudio, is there any way to fix this without reinstalling PulseAudio? If there isn't then can you please recommend some good Bluetooth managers?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out,I was able to disable PulseAudio rather than removing it with auto remove or purge by editing the file /etc/pulse/client.conf and setting auto spawn to no.